# Add images to a contact in Contacts

Tags: macos, formatting, contacts.app

Is there a way to modify the type style and add JPEGs or PNGs to Contacts?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. The contacts app allows for quite a bit of customization, including adding a profile picture. Can you explain exactly what you need to do? There may be other ways to accomplish your task.

Comment: I'd like to add screenshots to a  card and not into that tiny circle image appearing on the upper left hand corner of the person's name.

Comment: Also, I'd like to bold the standard type face used in contacts. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: hmm but why exactly? you just don't like how it looks?

Comment: If I could edit the text format w. some basics like bold, underline and italic, my cards in Contacts would be more useful. And if I could add pics like someone's business card to their Contacts card, well that would be supreme.

Comment: I still fail to see how that's useful. You can add fields and give them custom names as needed? Click the plus sign on the bottom of the contact to add fields and you can click on fields and change their title. For business cards, why not just bring over all that info into fields? If you need to store images one off, you can always upload to imgur and paste a link in the contact. You may also want to research other apps for storing contacts that are more robust, Apple intentionally keeps things simple. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The only media which can be added to a contact is as a profile photo. Notes only permits plain text, like other contact fields. Therefore unfortunately it's not possible to do this currently.

Comment: Can you edit "plain text" somehow?